# Item for Empty State of RecyclerView is not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display an "empty state" View when there are no items to display and what I did is add another viewType :

```
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private static final int EMPTY_STATE = 2;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset == null ? 1 : dataset.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (dataset == null) {
        return EMPTY_STATE;
    } else if (position == dataset.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) {
        return LOADING;
    } else {
        return ITEM;
    }
}
```

If dataset == null, I'm returning the view for the Empty State.

I have also added the appropriate code for  :

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM:
            viewHolder = getFeedItemViewHolder(parent, inflater);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            viewHolder = new LoadingVH(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false));
            break;
        case EMPTY_STATE:
            viewHolder = new EmptyStateVH(inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_first_time_text, parent, false));
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}
```

and for `onBindViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case ITEM:
             // code here...
           break;
        case EMPTY_STATE:
            final EmptyStateVH emptyStateVH = (EmptyStateVH) holder;
            break;
     }
}
```

But the above code is not working. Shouldn't with a Null dataset return an EMPTY_VIEW ? Is the logic wrong and I should find another way to do this? What I want to avoid is to move the logic to the `Activity` where I would have i.e a `FrameLayout` with an invisible overlapping View for the empty state which I would change the visibility to `VISIBLE` when there are no items. I want to avoid it since I 've got one `MainActivity` and many `Fragment`s and I want to use a different empty state for each one.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that `dataset` is not null, but empty (therefore dataset.size() returns 0)?

Comment: that;s correct! My mistake :/ Thanks for helping. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Answer with explanation and suggested fix added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weak point seams to be here:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset == null ? 1 : dataset.size();
}
```

If your dataset is not null, but only empty (dataset.size() == 0), this will basically break your code. A little fix will prevent this from happening:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (dataset == null || dataset.isEmpty()) ? 1 : dataset.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private static final int EMPTY_STATE = 2;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset.size() == 0? 1 : dataset.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (dataset.size() == 0) {
        return EMPTY_STATE;
    } else if (position == dataset.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) {
        return LOADING;
    } else {
        return ITEM;
    }
}
```